# HTTPS and trailing dot in domain

Tags: domain-name-system, https, certificate

Is it possible to solve the scenario where a web server is served behind HTTPS, and must be accessible both with `www.domain.com` and `www.domain.com.`? And notice the trailing dot.

An example for all: [GitHub](https://github.com.)

The certificate of course is for `github.com` not for `github.com.`. Is this problem somehow solvable? Am I completely misunderstanding the DNS architecture?

Comment: You don't need to use the trailing dot. What are you really doing?

Comment: GoDaddy and Comodo certs appear to work with the trailing dot just fine. Does yours not? Why do you care?

Comment: You would need to find a CA that would issue a certificate that had a name with trailing dot listed as a subject alternate name. I don't know of any that do that.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: You would if you needed to ensure the correct domain is accessed. For example "example.com" may be resolved to what "example.com.badguy.com" resolves to if someone has "badguy.com" in their DNS search order. (For example, a friend of mine once had the domain "router.com". A lot of people who had "com" in their search order would type `telnet router` and wind up connecting to him. They should be typing `telnet router.`.

Comment: Actually I'm not working on nothing in particular. I'm starting to extend my knowledge about networking and I came to the fact the a fqdn can be used also on http requests. My curiosity was: should I in future certificate request ask for both domain.tld and domain.tld.?

Comment: @ceejayoz: This is a browser/client-specific issue, not CA. What GoDaddy- or Comodo-issued certs did you test with? What browser/client did you test with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you have a cert with a Common Name or Subject Alternative Name (sometimes called a UCC certificate) that matches the hostname **exactly as it is typed**, the browser will report a name mismatch.

Most (all?) browsers appear to do this. See [*Bug 134402 - URLs with trailing dots in host names (FQDN) produce cert name mismatches*](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=134402) for a discussion of Mozilla's position on this issue. From thier perspective, there's just not enough upside to making such a change, since there are so few, if any, reasons a trailing dot should be included in a URL.

Basically browser vendors, as well as anyone else producing a product that verifies certificates, have to be conservative in any case where they are matching hostnames to certs. Making assumptions as to what the user intended is generally considered "bad". If you are not careful, you can end up in a situation where a hostname in a non-specific url (ex. `https://www`) is matched to a cert for `https://www.<a_domain_in_your_suffix_search_list>`, where that resultant domain is not controlled by the same entity as the originally typed name. This is one exception to my rule for always using a trailing dot in FQDNs. The trailing dot is generally a good idea as it is unambiguous and requires fewer queries to resolve, but not all applications deal with it gracefully.

Good catch though, you are WAY ahead of most people in terms of your understanding of "how DNS/SSL/browsers work".

Comment: Thank you so much. Very good insight.

I was also wondering about virtual hosting, usually you just check against the Host Header, which could contain "wrong" values such as only `"www"` if you put `google.com` on your search list.

Comment: I recently came across a good reason to use a FQDN with a trailing dot: to reduce DNS queries in a Kubernetes cluster. 
Ref: https://pracucci.com/kubernetes-dns-resolution-ndots-options-and-why-it-may-affect-application-performances.html
By appending a dot, we can tell the `resolver` that the given name is a FQDN and it should not attempt the suffixes in the search list, thus avoiding unnecessary DNS queries.